# All xpages in DB sometimes never load

Tags: xpages

During development, I sometimes make a mistake in my code (yes I know that is had to believe :) ) and when the page attempted to be displayed in the browser, the browser just sits and spins trying to load the page but the page never loads.

After this occurs, no other pages in that db react the same and this is true for all users of the database.  No other users can use the database during this "lockup" period.

Pages in the problem db will not work for any user.  Xpages in other databases on that server continue to work fine.  Http from traditional forms and view work fine in the problem db.  It seems only xpages are affected.

It seems over a period of time, the pages for the problem db will work again.

What would be causing the lockup issue and is there and way to fix it immediately?

Comment: If I make a copy of the db then xpages in the copy work.  But all xPages in the original db continue not to work.

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop to me (i.e. forgetting the getNextEntry / getNextDocument inside a while loop). If that's the case, restarting HTTP should do the trick.

Comment: Bruce, maybe you should use the new copy. I had a similar issue with an older NSF. Code for a sortable data table would just not work. Made a copy of the NSF and it worked fine. It "appeared" that everything was identical but after trying for a few days to determine what the issue was with the first NSF, we decided to scrap it and use the new one. Everything has been fine since then.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce you know that you will roast in hell for developing on a production database on a production server :-)
The steps to remedy:

- check all errors (in the error pane in designer) and fix them
- do a clean build of your app
- restart the http server
- Optional action: Compact -c

Hope that helps

P.S.: We all will join you down there ;-)

Comment: It was not in prod.  It was on a dev server.  Since http is working for other DBs, including normal notes forms on the problem db.  Would restarting http resolve the issue?

Comment: Did the clean build of the application help? It feels like a Java mess-up (which would impact only one NSF)